# Find out when document.location.href has been completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, browser

I have a button that lets users download a file. 
The file is returned from the server in the Response (binaries set as attachment), and I am letting the browser handle the file download from there on out.

Im doing the following on button click:

```
var fileUrl = 'mysite.com?id=12345';
document.location.href = fileUrl;
```

This will load the file, however, it can take a couple of seconds. I would like to show a preloader but then ofcourse I have to know when the file has been downloaded completed. Since I'm staying on the same page, is there a method or callback that tells if the 'new' location is loaded and thus I can hide the preloader?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect when browser receives file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you can download the file twice, you could load the file in a hidden iframe and detect when the iframe is done loading. Then, the file is already cached and should download quickly.

Comment: I didnt 'really' use this 2-downloads route, however, I did go the iFrame route, including a cookie to set the status, based on the mentioned duplicate question.